# Add "if arguement" against a Pipe for a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm new at writing code and batch files. I'm trying to automate a user setup by allowing the user to issue the following batch file:

Command Executed = "BVT_AudioDecode_Setup.bat V:\WP\BVT\Audio\Decode 10.42.233.237"

```
@echo off
::Conditions leading to errors if the batch script is not executed correctly
if "%1"=="" and "%2"=="" goto error1
if "%1"=="" goto error2
if "%2"=="" goto error3

::Allows user to set the "Source Path" to copy the testcase files from
set source=%1
::Allows user to set the "Destination Path" to copy the testcase files from
set IP_Address=%2

::Tells the user what the "Source" and "Destination" Paths are
echo Source Path = %1
echo Destination Path = %2
echo.
powershell.exe -File "bat_script.ps1" %1 %2 -NoProfile -NoExit


goto end
:error1
echo.
echo Error Syntax: BVT_AudioDecode_Setup.bat "Source_Path\AudioDecode_Testcase_Folder" "Device IP Address"
echo.
echo For example: BVT_AudioDecode_Setup.bat V:\WP\BVT\Audio\Decode 10.42.233.237
echo              -or-
echo              BVT_AudioDecode_Setup.bat C:\WP\BVT\Audio\Decode 10.42.233.237
echo.
echo.
goto end
:error2
echo.
echo Error Syntax: BVT_AudioDecode_Setup.bat "Source_Path\AudioDecode_Testcase_Folder" "Device IP Address"
echo.
echo For example: BVT_AudioDecode_Setup.bat V:\WP\BVT\Audio\Decode 10.42.233.237
echo              -or-
echo              BVT_AudioDecode_Setup.bat C:\WP\BVT\Audio\Decode 10.42.233.237
echo.
echo.
goto end
:error3
echo.
echo Error Syntax: BVT_AudioDecode_Setup.bat "Source_Path\AudioDecode_Testcase_Folder" "Device IP Address"
echo.
echo For example: BVT_AudioDecode_Setup.bat V:\WP\BVT\Audio\Decode 10.42.233.237
echo              -or-
echo              BVT_AudioDecode_Setup.bat C:\WP\BVT\Audio\Decode 10.42.233.237
echo.
echo.
goto end
:end
```

This was tested and it works.

Now I am trying to add/test a simple block of code, but I cannot find the correct syntax. Yes, I have been googling for the last 3 hours. Here is what I am trying to do:

Command Executed = "Random.bat C:\Users"

Command Executed = "Random.bat C:\InvalidDirectory"

```
::Conditions leading to errors if the batch script is not executed correctly
@ECHO OFF
SET "mypath=%1"
ECHO %mypath%
cd %mypath% | find "%invalidpath%"
Echo %invalidpath%

If "%invalidpath%=The system cannot find the path specified." (
goto error1)
else (
goto BeginTest)

::Begins the testcase
:BeginTest
::Do some stuff
goto end
:error1
echo Error: Invalid Path
goto end
:end
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated...

Comment: What exactly appears to be the problem? What's going wrong? Why do you think it's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the IF EXIST statement to check for the presence of a directory. For example, to test for C:\WIN and then change to C:\WIN if it exists :

```
C:
IF NOT EXIST "C:\WIN\." GOTO NOWINDIR
CD \WIN
:NOWINDIR
```

Answer (score 2):

because the "not-found-answer" from "cd xxxx" will vary with the language of your windows-installation you should prefer a language-independent solution.
Use %errrorlevel% for that.

`cd c:\existingpath\` will return an errorlevel of "0"

`cd c:\notexistingpath\` will return "1"

so a good solution would be:

```
SET "mypath=%1"
ECHO %mypath%
cd %mypath% 
If %errorlevel%=0 goto BeginTest else goto error1
```

...

Answer (score 1):

It worked, thanks. Here is what I have in case anyone else runs into this problem:

```
::Conditions leading to errors if the batch script is not executed correctly
@ECHO OFF
SET "source=%1"
ECHO %source%
IF NOT EXIST "%source%" goto error1
ECHO Directory Exists
cd %source%

goto end
:error1
echo Error: Invalid Path
goto end
:end
```

Now I need an if condition for a true IP Address

```
::Conditions leading to errors if the batch script is not executed correctly
@ECHO OFF
SET "IP_Address=%1"
ECHO %IP_Address%

::Checks if the IP Address is valid
IF NOT EXIST "%IP_Address%" goto error2
ECHO Directory Exists

goto end
:error1
echo.
echo Error: Invalid Path
echo %source%
goto end
:error2
echo.
echo Error: Invalid IP Address
echo %IP_Address%
goto end
:end
```

It automatically checks to see if the IP Address is a path. I could add a "\\" in front of the "IF NOT EXIST "\\%IP_Address%" goto error2", but the issue with this is that the computer will not be able to connect to the device unless it uses either telnet, or "Open-Device" command through powershell. It can however ping that IP Address.

Is there is a way to setup to read a successful ping vs unsuccessful ping??

Answer (score 1):

same solution with %errorlevel%

```
ping -n 1 -w 100 %ip-address%
if %errorlevel%=0 then goto doesexist else goto cannotreach
```

...

All commands will return an errorlevel. Normally Zero, if all was ok, and a non-zero- value for errors.

Answer (score 0):

It's still not working correctly with the IP address listing, but I am closer with your help. Here is what I have when I execute the bat with a valid IP Address to ping:

```
::Conditions leading to errors if the batch script is not executed correctly
@ECHO OFF
SET IP_Address=%1
ECHO %IP_Address%

::Checks if the IP Address is valid
ping -n 1 -w 1000 %IP_Address%
if not "%errorlevel%=0" goto error2

goto end
:error2
echo.
echo Error: Invalid IP Address
echo %IP_Address%
goto end
:end
```

Upon execution this is what I am seeing in cmd:

```
c:\>Random.bat 192.168.1.46
192.168.1.46

Pinging 192.168.1.46 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.46: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.46:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms
goto was unexpected at this time.
```

Once this is solved, I would also like to know a way to hide the output:

```
Pinging 192.168.1.46 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.46: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.46:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms
```

Answer (score 0):

to hide the output use >nul

```
ping -n 1 -w 1000 %IP_Address% 1>nul 2>nul
```

`1>nul` will  send the "normal" output to nirvana

`2>nul` will send the errormessages to nirvana

So if you use " 1>nul" (or just " >nul") you will have the errormessage on the screen, but not the "reply", "statistics" and that kind of stuff.

I don't understand the "unexpected goto" just now - I will have a look on that tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for your help up to this point and I will appreciate it if you can solve why the goto does not work. I noticed if I try:

`if not %errorlevel%=0 goto error2`
 -or-
`if not "%errorlevel%"=0"" goto error2`, it will say unexpected =0. I hope this helps in solving it.

Comment: AAAARGHH! That's the reason, one should not work late in the night: you will not see the obvious.  Use if %errorlevel%==0 (double == instead of single =). See also if /?  (you used the right Syntax in your initial post)

Answer (score 0):

Ah I finally found it after looking up usage for errorlevel

```
::Conditions leading to errors if the batch script is not executed correctly
@ECHO OFF
SET IP_Address=%1
ECHO %IP_Address%

::Checks if the IP Address is valid
ping -n 1 -w 100 %IP_Address% 1>nul
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" goto error2

:error2
echo.
echo Error: Invalid IP Address
echo %IP_Address%
goto end
:end
```

Thanks for the help everyone.